# Paperclip attached mp3 gets corrupted after upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html5-audio

So, I originally thought the problem was PJAX/MediaElement but, after a couple tests I have found playing the un-uploaded mp3's there is no issue, but, when playing the files uploaded (in public/system/songs/) the file will not play all the way through in any app.

Comment: Could it be something with paperclip? That's how the songs are added...

Comment: Went and tried to play the uploaded (paperclip) files in iTunes, and, They act the same... It must be paperclips issue. Will update if this is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It must have been an issue with my set up locally. Because it works fine with s3 and heroku.